# GNOME's touchpad and mouse settings completely changed after installing XFCE4 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, touchpad, xfce, xinput

On my Ubuntu 20.04 installation, in addition to GNOME, I installed XFCE as an additional DE. After doing this (and not changing any settings) I noticed that my touchpad began behaving differently across **all** desktop environments. So when switching back to GNOME, the XFCE default touchpad settings are still applied.

Specifically:

- Natural scrolling can no longer be enabled in the horizontal direction.
- Accelaration feels different to GNOME's preset.
- No more palm rejection when typing.
- Scrolling inertia enabled (pages keep scrolling for a bit after releasing fingers from touchpad)

Things I have tried:

- Purging XFCE from my system.
- Searching the dconf editor for relevant settings which I've seen other forum posts telling me to change.
- Manual changes using xinput, but these aren't persistent, and I would like to find the exact config file causing these issues.

How can I get back to GNOME's default touchpad settings?

Comment: Multiple DEs can have complexities (I'm a *lover* of multiple DEs so am a little experienced with some *quirks*).. I usually (*when I notice changes like you describe*) look at config files that changed on installation of the new desktop (ie. *files that have date/time stamp marked at install time; which can be found in apt logs*).  This is usually easily discovered before you try too many other things to revert/fix the issue (ie. easier when you've got fewer changes).  ie `find -mtime` (`-mmin` etc) type exploration..

Comment: @guiverc thank you for the suggestion. In hindsight that would have been a good thing to do, alas I think I have made too many changes to be able to detect the source of the problem...